# Replacing <a> tags that have two pairs of double quotes

Tags: ruby, xml, css-selectors, nokogiri

I have asked a similar question before but this one is slightly different

I have content with this sort of links in:

```
<a href=""ssLINK/prof-steve-jackson"">Professor Steve Jackson</a>
```

[UPDATE]

And this is how i read it:

```
content = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element[@name='Body']").inner_text
```

The links has two pairs of double quotes after the `href=`.

I am trying to strip out the tag and retrieve only the text like so:

```
Professor Steve Jackson
```

To do this I'm using the same method which works for this sort of link which has only a single pair of double quotes:

```
<a href="ssLINK/world">World</a>
```

This returns World:

```
content = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(content_with_link)
content.css('a[href^="ssLINK"]')
.each{|a| a.replace("<>#{a.content}</>")}
=>World
```

When I try To do the same for the link that has two pairs of double quotes it complains:

```
content = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(content_with_link)
content.css('a[href^=""ssLINK""]')
.each{|a| a.replace("<>#{a.content}</>")}
```

Error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in
`on_error': unexpected 'ssLINK' after '[:prefix_match, "\"\""]' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

Anyone know how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: That's going to be a little difficult since the double quotes cause the HTML to be malformed...

Comment: I agree. you have any suggestion om how to approach it?

Comment: Do every `<a>` tag has href's with two `""` enclosing them or its just the one with `ssLINK`

Comment: @AmitThawait i cant do "" as it will remove other links. how would i do just ssLINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two ways to do it, but it depends on whether :  every `<a>` tag has href's with two `""` enclosing them or its just the one with ssLINK

Assume

```
output = []

input_text = '<a href=""ssLINK/prof-steve-jackson"">Professor Steve Jackson</a>'
```

1) If `a` tags has href with `""` only with `ssLink` then just do

```
Nokogiri::HTML(input_text).css('a[href=""]').each do |nokogiri_obj|
  output << nokogiri_obj.text
end

# => output = ["Professor Steve Jackson"]
```

2) If all the `a` tags has href with `""`then you can try this

```
nokogiri_a_tag_obj = Nokogiri::HTML(input_text).css('a[href=""]')
nokogiri_a_tag_obj.each do |nokogiri_obj|
  output << nokogiri_obj.text if nokogiri_obj.has_attribute?('sslink')
end

# => output = ["Professor Steve Jackson"]
```

With this second approach if

```
input_text = '<a href=""ssLINK/prof-steve-jackson"">Professor Steve Jackson</a> Some other Text<a href=""abcd"">Second link</a>'
```

then also the output will be `["Professor Steve Jackson"]`

Comment: I seem to get this error 'undefined method `empty?' See the update, I have added the line on how I store the content. maybe that's the issue. p.s I need option 2. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @devArled what's the output of `content = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element[@name='Body']")` ?

Comment: @devArled I think , you are doing `.inner_text` in that line is the issue... just remove it

Comment: I am reading the body node from an xml file which has the content together with the <a> tags

Comment: @devArled Try removing the `inner_text` method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41120/discussion-between-devarled-and-amit-thawait)

Answer (score 0):

Your content is not XML, so any attempt to solve the problem using XML tools such as XSLT and XPath is doomed to failure. Use a regex approach, e.g. awk or Perl. However, it's not immediately obvious to me how to match

```
<a href="" sometext"">
```

without also matching

```
<a href="" sometext="">
```

so we need to know a bit more about this syntax that you are trying to parse.

Comment: so my content live is a '.xml' file as you can see above I am using 'xpath' to get the 'inner_text' of the body node. then I'm using 'Nokogiri' and 'css-selector' to perform what I want to achieve. If this is not possible is there away of being able to get all '<a>' tags and substitute every "" with "?

Comment: Your content is not XML, so any attempt to use XPath on it should fail, by design.